# How to use Laravel/sanctum in package development

Tags: laravel-7, include-guards, package-development, laravel-sanctum

I try to use the Laravel/Sanctum in a custom Laravel package.
As in a default Laravel application, I added it to the composer file, added the migration and set it up in the routes file.

The next error message appears:

> "Auth guard [sanctum] is not defined."

I hope it is even possible to use sanctum in another package?

### Composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": "7.4.*",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.2"
  },
```

### routes file:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
Route::post('/approve', ['uses' => 'MemberRequestController@response', 'response' => 'approve'])->name('approve_member_request');
}
```

### ServiceProvider

```php
/**
     *
     */
    private function registerRoutes()
    {
        Route::group($this->routeConfig(), function () {
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../../routes/api.php');
        });
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    private function routeConfig(): array
    {
        return [
            'prefix' => ums::path(),
            'namespace' => 'martijn\UMS\Http\Controllers',
            'middleware' => ['api', 'auth:sanctum']
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should publish the `Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider`.

It will register the missing guard.

Comment: I added the serviceprovider to my package and added the config file to my config. Thanks! You saved my time!

Answer (score 1):

Started work after me removed content of folder `bootstrap/cache/` manually

No cache/view/routes clearings helped

Answer (score 0):

In my host DirectAdmin, I manually reuploaded vendor folder and after facing this error

`Auth guard [sanctum] is not defined`

I reuploaded bootstrap folder.

Everything works fine right now.

Answer (score -1):

In my case problem was in `RouteServiceProvider,` default sign in was redirecting to `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` and public `const HOME = '/dashboard';`
Which I didn't had anymore, so replace it just with existing view.